# How to add the thick grey line in between the font icons

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

In my application I have the 10 icons which are added as side by side within a row and my requirement is to add the thick greyline in between the icons as given below.

[image]

and the code is..

```
<div>
<i class="stl icon icon-smiley-face-1"></i>
<i class="stl icon icon-smiley-face-2"></i>
<i class="stl icon icon-smiley-face-3"></i>
</div>
```

Like the above I have 10 icons .Now I have to add the thick grey line in between the icons and below the icon it has to show the number as in image.

I tried with hr tag but not working as expected. Can anyone help me on the same.

Comment: _"and below the icon it has to show the number"_ - looks like those numbers are the actual relevant information here, the rest is just "decoration". So this should _start_ with a proper HTML structure that represents these numbers - like a list with lis items containing those numbers. (And if this is eventually supposed to become a "ranking" component, the numbers should probably be labels assigned to corresponding radio buttons.)

Comment: Have you tried using `.icon::before` and `.icon::after` in your CSS? Using this method you can insert your grey lines automatically, one before each smiley and one after each smiley. With no padding or margins I hope each "`after` grey line" will connect to the following "`before` grey line." Here is some further info from CSS Tricks. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added `spans` to your code for numbering .
if you have more icons ,for centring number with icons you should modify `left` property in `.icons` class.

```css
.box{
  width:50%;
  margin: 200px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  counter-reset: number;
}
.material-icons{
  color: #fff;
}
.material-icons:first-of-type:after,
.material-icons:last-of-type:after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  border-top: 4px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.material-icons:last-of-type:after{
  transform:translate(-100%);
}
.icons{
  position: relative;
  left: 8%;
  top: 20px;
}
.icons:after{
  content: counter(number);
  counter-increment: number;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="icons"></span><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
    <span class="icons"></span><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
    <span class="icons"></span><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
    <span class="icons"></span><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
    <span class="icons"></span><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
    <span class="icons"></span><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @M.R MRF it is working fine and could you please help me how to add the numbers below the icons as in the above image